# Rails How to set multiple polymorphic in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails How to set multiple polymorphic in controller?

Some of codes as follows:

### question.rb

```
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
```

### comment.rb

```
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true

has_many :reports, :as => :reportable, :dependent => :destroy
```

### report.rb

```
belongs_to :reportable, polymorphic: true
```

### routes.rb

```
resources :questions do

  resources :comments do 

    resources :reports

end
```

And then in `_comment.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-times mr2 fa-fw'></i>Report".html_safe,new_question_comment_report_path(@question,@comment),remote: true %>
```

### My reports_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :set_reportable

  def new
    @report = @reportable.reports.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_to @reportable
      end
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @report = @reportable.reports.new report_params
    @report.reporter_id = current_user.id
    if @report.save
      redirect_to @reportable
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    @report.destroy
  end

  private
  def set_reportable
    if params[:comment_id]
      @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
      @reportable = @question.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    end
  end

  def report_params
    params.require(:report).permit(:content,:radio_content)
  end
end
```

### new.js.erb of reports

```
$("body").append("<%= j render "reports/reports" %>")
$("#tip-offs").modal('show')
```

### My _reports.html.erb

```
<div class="modal tip-offs in" id="tip-offs" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          <span data-model="action">Report</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <%= form_for [@reportable,@report] do |f| %>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="pbt5">
            <%= f.text_area :content,row:3, class: "form-control",placeholder: "report more" %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
        <%= f.submit "report",class:"btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

### If the report url in comment such as:

```
/questions/6/comments/15/reports/new
```

I get the error:

```
Processing by ReportsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"question_id"=>"6", "comment_id"=>"15"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`commentable_id` = 6 AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Question' AND `comments`.`id` = 15 LIMIT 1
  Rendering reports/new.js.erb
  Rendered reports/_reports.html.erb (24.4ms)
  Rendered reports/new.js.erb (25.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `comment_reports_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fb020559858>:0x00007fb022d02c38>
Did you mean?  comment_like_tag:
  app/views/reports/_reports.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_reports__reports_html_erb___1071799134587169621_70197237478960'
  app/views/reports/new.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_reports_new_js_erb___4579025611719430071_70197237521140'
```

I think maybe I had a erro in set_reportable in **`set_reportable`** in `reports_controller.rb`, If it is , how can I get the right report url?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you include the complete stack trace of error?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @JagdeepSingh , I had add more infomation about my quesiton, Could you have a look  and give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError - undefined method `comment_reports_path' for

Your `comments` and `reports` both are nested under `questions`, so you need to change

```
<%= form_for [@reportable,@report] do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for [@question,@reportable,@report] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , @Pavan, it's right as your codes. But in fact, the `report` is polymorphic, I wish that` _reports.html.web` can be used not only in question , but it can used in others controllers, such as `article` and so on . So is there any methods that I can get the right `new_question_comment_report_path` in `reports_controller.rb`, not to change the `form_for`?

Answer (score 0):

Your comments path is nested under your questions path.

```
resources :questions do
  resources :comments do 
    resources :reports
end
```

But your form does not provide the question instance to build the URL:

```
<%= form_for [@reportable,@report] do |f| %>
```

This `[@reportable, @report]` expands to `comment_reports_path`, which does not exist.

You need to pass the question instance as well: `[@question, @reportable, @report]`, which would expand to `question_comment_reports_path`.

If you run `rake routes` (in Rails 5 it might be `rails routes`, not sure), you should see a list of all your routes and their paths. It makes it easier to reason about existing routes and the arguments they require.

Comment: Thanks for your help , @Mohamad, it's right as your codes. But in fact, the report is polymorphic, I wish that` _reports.html.web` can be used not only in question , but it can used in others controllers, such as article and so on . So is there any methods that I can get the right new_question_comment_report_path in reports_controller.rb, not to change the form_for?

Comment: OK, then you need to determine the parent association in the controller. I'll update my answer when I have some time.